# Move the last word of each line to be right aligned

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am creating an index for a big legal book. Each section and subsection and clauses are indexed.

These are copy pasted from the actual book and then, the page number is added.

It is a word file.

For example:

> 

Topic number 1 ……… 1.34

Topic number 2 ……… 1.37

Topic with long text ……… 1.45

Topic no 3 ……… 1.48**

I am trying to accomplish like this:

> 

Topic number 1 ………………………   1.34

Topic number 2 ………………………        1.37

Topic with long text …………………  1.45

Topic no 3 ………………………………           1.48

> 

The page numbers right aligned.

*Is there any way to do like this?*

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is it a word document or an excel file?

Comment: @Browniepoints Updated the question. It is a word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can set a right tab, with a dot leader.

Then pressing the tab key before the page number gives you both the right-alignment and the dot leader.

[image: screenshot of dialog box]

Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/106ow99ezhj14vp/deleteme%20-%20right%20tab.docx?dl=0) with these settings. These are paragraph formatting settings, best handled in a paragraph style. The TOC 1 style has this by default.

Here is a link to [MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on Setting Tabs](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/SettingTabs.htm).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome.